# If $f$ is a continuous function then does $f(x) = x \Leftrightarrow f(f(x)) = x$ hold?

Tags: functions, continuity

This question comes in the context of this other problem:

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous decreasing function with $f(0) > 0$. Prove that there exist an $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$ such that $f(f(\alpha)) = \alpha$.

To solve this you can use Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is an $\alpha \in (0,f(0))$ such that $h(\alpha)=f(\alpha)-\alpha = 0 \Rightarrow f(\alpha)=\alpha \Rightarrow f(f(\alpha)) = \alpha$. That is because $h(0) = f(0) > 0$ and $h(f(0)) = f(f(0)) - f(0) < f(0) - f(0) = 0$ ( $f(f(0)) < f(0)$ because $f(0)>0$ and $f$ is decreasing ).

However, in this proof I was looking for a solution to $f(x)=x$. This made me wonder if $($ $f(f(x)) = x \Leftrightarrow f(x)=x$ $)$ is true. If it is, that $\alpha$ from my problem is also unique ( because $h$ is strictly decreasing so injective )

Comment: If you take an involution ($f\circ f=\mathrm{id}$), you will get some counterexamples. E.g. $f(x)=-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** Consider what happens if $f(x) = -x$. Exercises:

1. Is $f$ continuous in this case?
2. One direction of the biconditional implication fails. Which one?